# Is there a way to automatically generate equals and hashcode method in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, list

In Java when you want to have remove correctly object from a generic `Collection` by `remove()` method you have to implement `equals(Object o)` and `remove()` method which can be automatically generated in Eclipse. Example of that method looks like that ---> below.

1. How to automatically generate that method in C# (Visual Studio, I'm on VS2013)?
2. Maybe it is not necessary to make `List.Remove()` method working properly?
3. IF it is not possible automatically how the reference `Equals` methods should look like? I mean how it should look like.
4. Is `Equals()` method is even used in `List.Remove()` if so could you show me how the `Equals()` should be implemented to return true if we compare THE SAME OBJECTS (same address in memory)

---

```
  @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((centerPanel == null) ? 0 :          centerPanel.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lowerPanel == null) ? 0 : lowerPanel.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        LayoutDemo other = (LayoutDemo) obj;
        if(centerPanel == null) {
            if(other.centerPanel != null)
                return false;
        } else if(!centerPanel.equals(other.centerPanel))
            return false;
        if(lowerPanel == null) {
            if(other.lowerPanel != null)
                return false;
        } else if(!lowerPanel.equals(other.lowerPanel))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with _automatically_? Even eclipse does not know how you want to implement these methods, so what equality for your custom object means. If you just want to create the method bodies let your class implement `IEqualityComparer`. If you click on the red error-line below the interface, Visual Studio will suggest to create them automatically. But they will contain only `throw new NotImplementedException();`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It does know, example above.

Comment: so eclipse adds all properties of your class into `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or just a single or none? What is autogenerated above, everything? `Equals` and `GethashCode` are not trivial for complex objects.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is `Equals()` method is even used in `List.Remove()` if so could you show me how the `Equals()` should be implemented to return true if we compare THE SAME OBJECTS (same address in memory)

Comment: `Equals` is used in [`List.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) and to compare two objects by reference use: `Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)`. It's always worth to read the documentation first. You'll find the relevant information in the remarks section.

Comment: Just copy-paste your class into a Java project in Eclipse, hit "generate hashCode and equals" and then copy paste back. Still less work that acctually writing those functions.

Answer (score 19):

Lo and behold, since November 2017 even Visual Studio itself can generate **meaningful implementation** of these methods (at least since version 15.5.2).

Just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or right click inside the class and choose "Quick Actions" and then "**Generate Equals and GetHashCode**"

Docs for the feature:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods

```
    public class Foo
    {
       public Bar Bar { get; set; }
       public string FooBar { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var foo = obj as Foo;
        return foo != null &&
               EqualityComparer<Bar>.Default.Equals(Bar, foo.Bar) &&
               FooBar == foo.FooBar;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hashCode = 181846194;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<Bar>.Default.GetHashCode(Bar);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(FooBar);
        return hashCode;
    }

}
```

---

Update: Note tough, that you still might not want to trust VS completely and test Equals, since if your class contains Collection, Equals will depend on reference equality once more as this term is used:

```
EqualityComparer<IList<Foo>>.Default.Equals(SomeFoos, other.SomeFoos);
```

OMG anyone?
And ReSharper does that too.

Comment: Looks like VS for Mac Community Edition has this option too, but nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?", one has to use this technique with VS quite often...other than that, I can think of only upgrading to newest version. I tried on both Enterprise and Communit Editions on Windows, both working fine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on the latest version.

Comment: You need to right click on the line that declare the class. Also, you won't see the option if your class already contain the Equals methods.

Answer (score 12):

### Automatic `Equals()` generation at design time

If you want to generate it once and then maintain the generated source code manually (e.g. if the class changes), Resharper is a useful tool, as @ThomasWeller already mentioned in his answer.

*Note that this approach has potential for hard to find bugs, because you need to remember to adapt the `Equals()` implementation when you change the class. To avoid this, use the following approach:*

### Automatic `Equals()` generation at runtime (static initialization time)

If you want a solution that dynamically generates `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods at runtime, you can use [Equ](https://github.com/thedmi/Equ) (I'm the author of that library). Equ generates the equality methods at static initialization time and caches them, so after static initialization, performance is the same as an explicit implementation.

Here is a simple example:

```
class Address : MemberwiseEquatable<Address>
{
  public Address(string street, string city)
  {
    Street = street;
    City = city;
  }

  public string Street { get; }
  public string City { get; }
}
```

With this, the following expression is `true`:

```
new Address("Baker Street", "London") == new Address("Baker Street", "London")
```

This is the easiest way of using Equ: Just inherit from `MemberwiseEquatable<TSelf>`. Note that there are other possibilities if you can not / don't want to inherit from a base class.

#### Remark on compare *by value* vs *by reference*

In your last question you want to know how to write an `Equals` method that compares objects by "address in memory". This is called reference equality comparison and is the default `Equals()` implementation that every class inherits from `object`. So to get reference equality on your class, just **don't** override `Equals()`.

You should however think carefully about which objects you want to compare by reference, and which you want to compare by value. If you use the domain-driven design terminology, *value objects* should be compared by value, whereas *entities* should be compared by reference or by ID.

Answer (score 5):

No. [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do that (along with other goodies such as implementing `IEquatable<T>`) but plain VS cannot.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's not a full auto-generation, but in Visual Studio 2015, there is a way to auto generate at least the method stub of the Hashcode() and a Equals() function.

1. In the class you wish to add them to, type Equals
   [image]
2. Bring your curser to the end of Equals and hit tab.
   [image]
3. Remove the NotImplementedExceptions and add some tests for equality.

I hope this is helpful to someone!