# Compare One Model Class to Another C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, optimization

At the moment I currently have a `CompanyModel` that looks like so;

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddr1 { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddr2 { get; set; }
    public string CompanyTown { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCounty { get; set; }
    public string CompanyPcode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyTelephone { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAltTelephone { get; set; }
    public string CompanyFax { get; set; }
    public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }
    public string CompanyWhoEntered { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompanyDateEntered { get; set; }
    public string CompanyTimeEntered { get; set; }
    public string CompanyGeographicArea { get; set; }
    public string CompanySearchName { get; set; }

}
```

What I would like to do is initialise two `CompanyModels` and compare the contents of both to ensure that both Companies have exactly the same data in their fields. Currently I am doing an absolutely horrendous concatenation of `If` statements as I am unsure of another way. This currently looks like so;

```
if (eCDetails.CompanyName == cCompanyDetails.CompanyName)
   {
      if (eCDetails.CompanyName == cCompanyDetails.CompanyName)
      {
          if (eCDetails.CompanyAddr1 == cCompanyDetails.CompanyName)
          {
```

and so on and so forth (it's terrible). Is there an easier to way to ensure that both `CompanyModels` are equivalent?

Comment: You could at least stop the nesting by reversing the logic: `if(x.prop != y.prop) return false;` and `return true;` at the end.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454519/best-way-to-compare-two-complex-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the [conditional-AND (`&&`) operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx)?

```
if (eCDetails.CompanyName == cCompanyDetails.CompanyName &&
    eCDetails.CompanyName == cCompanyDetails.CompanyName &&
    eCDetails.CompanyAddr1 == cCompanyDetails.CompanyName &&
    // etc...
```

If you have [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper), you can use it to [auto-generate this code (and more) for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652567/is-there-a-way-to-auto-generate-gethashcode-and-equals-with-resharper).

Comment: mutiple && operator not recomended

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj Says whom?

Comment: @HimBromBeere the code is not easy to readble and not easy to maintain

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj I find it exactly as easy to maintain as nested `if`-statements but much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write an equals method ?

You can make something like that :

```
if (eCDetails.CompanyName != cCompanyDetails.CompanyName)
   { return false;
}
if (eCDetails.CompanyName != cCompanyDetails.CompanyName)
      {return false;
}
...
return true;
```

There's no many option to do what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

try this .. also you have to ignore some properties

```
public static bool PublicInstancePropertiesEqual<T>(this T self, T to, params string[] ignore) where T : class
{
    if (self != null && to != null)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var ignoreList = new List<string>(ignore);
        var unequalProperties =
            from pi in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            where !ignoreList.Contains(pi.Name)
            let selfValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(self, null)
            let toValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(to, null)
            where selfValue != toValue && (selfValue == null || !selfValue.Equals(toValue))
            select selfValue;
        return !unequalProperties.Any();
    }
    return self == to;
}
```

Orginal [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506096/comparing-object-properties-in-c-sharp)

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You may also implement `Equals` ony youd model-class:

```
class CompanyModel{
    public override bool Equals(object other) {
        var m = (CompanyModel) other;
        if (m == null) return false;

        return this.CompanyName == m.CompanyName &&
            this.CompanyName == m.CompanyName &&
            this.CompanyAddr1 == m.CompanyAddr1 // ...
    }
}
```

Now you can use `myModelInstance.Equals(anotherInstance)`.